# react lifting state up after login verified

Tags: reactjs, state, router, react-props, lifting

I'd like to create  component - - so that only authorised users can access it. the idea is that after receiving response 200 from backend in my Login component (which is a child component) I would somehow use authed:true as props in parent component. I understand this instructions https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html and also used similar procedure on other components. However, in this case, I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: this.props.authAfter200 is not a function
    at Login.handleSetAuthAfterVerified200 (AuthExample.js:325)
    at AuthExample.js:350
    at <anonymous>
```

The problem is I am not able to define function as a prop in my child component.

This is the function in my parent component that should get called as a prop.

```
  setAuthToTrue=() => {
    this.setState({authed:true})
  }
```

but I never get to here.

This is how I have defined my Route router in AuthExample(parent) component - using [react-router-with-props](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-with-props) for that:

```
  <PrivateRoute
    exact
    path="/private"
    redirectTo="/login"
    component={DailyNewsForUOnly}
    text="This is a private route"
    authAfter200={this.setAuthToTrue}
    authed={this.state.authed}
    />
```

this is the part in my child component - Login.js where I should be able to define function on my props to pass to the parent component - but I just cannot:

```
 handleSetAuthAfterVerified200() {
    //this.setState({authed:true})
    this.props.authAfter200()
  }


  verifyToken() {
    let request = {
      method: "post",
      url: "https://xxxxxx/xxxx/verify/",
      data: {
        user: this.state.email,
        token: this.state.token
      },
      withCredentials: true
    };
    console.log("request to verify");
    console.log(request);

    this.setState({ requestInMotion: true });

    axios(request)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response from verify", response);

        if (response.status === 200) {
          this.handleSetAuthAfterVerified200()
          this.setStateAfterVerified200()
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ requestInMotion: false, validationState: "error" });
        console.log(
          "this.state in the error part of response in verify",
          this.state
        );
      });
  }
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.props)` in your child component ? I suppose the props passed by the router will be in something like `this.props.router`.

Comment: console.log(this.props) in render of login component is giving : {match: {…}, location: {…}, history: {…}, staticContext: undefined, exact: true, …} - - seems I am unable to "push" a function to this props..

Comment: Can you see the `text` prop in the log ? Try removing the numbers from `authAfter200`, the router library you use may not handle that.

Comment: text property is seen - - and I also removed numbers from authAfter -
 - still the same.    this.props in render 
{match: {…}, location: {…}, history: {…}, staticContext: undefined, exact: true, …}
exact
:
true
history
:
{length: 2, action: "POP", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
location
:
{pathname: "/login", search: "", hash: "", state: {…}, key: "bcidni"}
match
:
{path: "/login", url: "/login", isExact: true, params: {…}}
path
:
"/login"
staticContext
:
undefined
text
:
"Hello world!"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: I think the biggest mistake so fat is that I am calling this authAfter in wrong place in my Router..I guess it should be in my Login component route and not in my DailyNewsForUOnly, which is the route that should be accessible to authorised users.. Will try firrst this

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest u to try to add debuggers in 
react-router-with-props/PrivateRoute.js and in 
react-router-with-props/renderMergedProps.js

and check if your props are actually being passed on properly.

he is doing very simple job of either allowing react to render your component or to redirect to url provided as prop.

I would suggest you rather use HigherOrderComponents or OnEnter route hook to handle these situations than a third party component.

Comment: OK, i made a silly mistake and writing props into the wrong path - it should be (of course) in <PrivateRoute ... login.. which I solved now. The props are passed as expected now  -the problem I am having is with render part . . I have a logic in render method of login component, based on some state variables - - although this state variables in login component are ok, redirect part to the route in history never gets called . .